# How to find a initial of name and make a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I got two files open and read like this

```
file1
Name, day1
Omi Aiz,90
Carin Jack,92
Swit Han,88

file2
Name, Day2
Omi Aiz, 20
Carin Jack,30
Swit Han,40
```

How to combine these into a single dictionary:

```
d={'OA':[90,20],'CJ':[92,30],'SH':[88,40]}
```

And find the average of day1 and day2

```
d={'OA':55,'CJ':61,'SH':64}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

this should do the first part

for the second, you just loop through and do average

```
def get_letters(name):
    names = name.split()
    return f'{names[0][0]}{names[1][0]}'

with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('file2', 'r') as f2:
    d = {}
    for l1, l2 in zip(f1[1:], f2[1:]):
        l1 = l1.split(',')
        l2 = l2.split(',')
        letters = get_letters(l1[0])
        d.append({letters:[l1[1], l2[1]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={}
def read(file):
     with open(file) as file:
          lines = file.read().split('\n')
          for line in lines:
               if line.startswith('Name,'):
                    lines.remove(line)
                    return lines
def sep(name):
     return ''.join((v[0] for v in name.split(' ')))
d = {}
for line in read('file1.txt'):
     if line:
          name,day=line.split(',')
          k = sep(name)
          d[k] = [int(day)]

for line in read('file2.txt'):
     if line:
          name,day=line.split(',')
          k = sep(name)
          if k in d:
               d[k].append(int(day))
print(d)
```